# How to check if one column value is greater than another in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to get results where value in one column is greater than values in another.

Example

```
select * FROM myTable where column time_taken is greater than time_spent
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * FROM myTable where time_taken > time_spent
```

To see a list of other operators available in MySql, have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html

Comment: I think you have something extra in there (I almost did the same thing typing mine)

Answer (score 2):

depend of the column type, both column are in the same data type, it can be done via

```
time_taken > time_spent
```

otherwise, some casting might required, like

```
cast(time_taken as signed) > time_spent
```

see [casting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from myTable where time_taken > time_spent
```

Figuring out less than, less than equal to, greater than or equal to is left as an exercise to the reader.